# Will not play in FF and huge player in IE8 - responsive

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am trying to get MediaElements to work responsively over multiple browsers.
I am testing it at this link.
http://testing.grappler.tk/mediaelement-js/

It works fine in Chrome. It will not play in FF and when I test it in IE8 it looks like this. In IE8+9 the play button disappears.
[image: http://pix.am/oIFU.png]
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking more time to test the code in different situations I found that the IE9 button problem was due to some css that the WordPress theme was using.

The IE8 problem was due to FitVids that was loaded with the theme. FitVids was trying to make the `object` responsive but it was not needed.

The Firefox problem of not playing the video was due to MiroVideoConverter. After trying another converter it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I traced through Firefox's decode operation. You appear to have a block with a timecode of -6 in a cluster of timecode 0. **EDIT**: A negative raw timecode is invalid, which causes the rest of the decode to fail.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure I understood everything you said. How can I fix this? Where do I need to look.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert on media coding, I just know how to set breakpoints in the debugger ;-)

Comment: I know that the video works with other players and when viewing the video directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about IE8, but for Firefox your WebM file is coming up as Content-Type application/octet-stream which Firefox cannot understand. You must set the content-type as outlined in step 0 on http://mediaelementjs.com/.

Also, your code has extra `<br>` tags inside the `<video>` tag which might be throwing off IE. And you don't need the `<object>` code unless you want to support non-HTML5 browsers (IE8 and below) with JavaScript turned off. Removing that code can simplify things.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have minified the HTMl so that WordPress does not add the `<br>`tags. I also have removed the `<object>` code. I have changed the video to files to ones hosted with Amazon. The content type should be correct also. http://pix.am/Lxrh.png I am still having the same problems.

Comment: I have a small update. I wanted to test my video outside the WordPress envoirnment. So I created two tests. http://jsbin.com/abebow/1 & http://jsfiddle.net/grappler/ngTDK/2/. Both of these work fine in IE8+9 but not in Firefox. So from this I deduce that the IE problems could be WordPress related.